# Convert between coordinate systems with GeoDjango

Tags: python, django, geolocation, geodjango, geopy

I'm trying to add coordinate information to my database, adding `django.contrib.gis` support to my app. I'm writing a `south` data migration that takes the addresses from the database, and asks Google for the coordinates (so far I think my best bet is to use `geopy` for this).

Next I need to convert the returned coordinates from `WGS84:4326`, Google's coordinate system, to `WGS84:22186`, my coordinate system.

I'm lost among the GeoDjango docs trying to find a way to do this. This far, I gather I need to do this:

```
gcoord = SpatialReference("4326")
mycoord = SpatialReference("22186")
trans = CoordTransform(gcoord, mycoord)
```

but then, I don't know how to use that `CoordTransform` object.. seems to be used by GDAL's data objects, but that's overkill for what I want to do..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

CoordTransform wouldn't work without GDAL that's true. But the rest of it is simple enough:

```
>>> from django.contrib.gis.gdal import SpatialReference, CoordTransform
>>> from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point
>>> gcoord = SpatialReference(4326)
>>> mycoord = SpatialReference(22186)
>>> trans = CoordTransform(gcoord, mycoord)

>>> pnt = Point(30, 50, srid=4326)
>>> print 'x: %s; y: %s; srid: %s' % (pnt.x, pnt.y, pnt.srid)
x: 30.0; y: 50.0; srid: 4326
>>> pnt.transform(trans)
>>> print 'x: %s; y: %s; srid: %s' % (pnt.x, pnt.y, pnt.srid)
x: 11160773.5712; y: 19724623.9117; srid: 22186
```

Note that point is transformed in place.

Comment: it's worth remembering that points are mutable and therefore the original coordinates will change when you transform it (even if it has been assigned to a new variable). You can create a copy of your point by creating a new point out your point which will not be mutated. For example: new_point = Point(old_point.x, old_point.y) so when you transform old_point, new_point will remain in the old projection.

Answer (score 12):

If you have all your libraries installed correctly there is no need to use the `CoordTransform` object, the point object's `transform` method will do the work for you if you know your desired `srid` value.

```
>>> from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point
>>> pnt = Point(30, 50, srid=4326)
>>> desired_srid = 22186
>>> pnt.transform(desired_srid)
>>> pnt.ewkt
u'SRID=22186;POINT (11160773.5712331663817167 19724623.9116888605058193)'
```