# Which SRID works with adding and sorting in SpatiaLite db?

Tags: django, spatial, geodjango, spatialite

I'm trying to make geodjango app. I'm using SQLite and SpatialLite.
I want to add shops, and be able to sort them from closest to furthest from my location.

When in my model I have:

```
location = gis_models.PointField(srid=4326, blank=True, null=True)
```

then adding works, but **sorting by distance does not work**, and I get:

```
SQLite does not support linear distance calculations on geodetic coordinate systems.
```

When I have:

```
location = gis_models.PointField(srid=3857, blank=True, null=True)
```

than **adding does not work**, and sorting works, and I get:

```
geo_shop.location violates Geometry constraint [geom-type or SRID not allowed]
```

What do I do to make them both work at the same time?

Answer (score -1):

Error while adding location is related to srid mismatch.

Use srid=3857 for sorting but when you are adding locations then convert them from 4326 to 3857 using the following method (from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6600969/convert-between-coordinate-systems-with-geodjango/6840772#6840772)):

```
>>> from django.contrib.gis.gdal import SpatialReference, CoordTransform
>>> from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point
>>> gcoord = SpatialReference(4326)
>>> mycoord = SpatialReference(22186)
>>> trans = CoordTransform(gcoord, mycoord)

>>> pnt = Point(30, 50, srid=4326)
>>> print 'x: %s; y: %s; srid: %s' % (pnt.x, pnt.y, pnt.srid)
x: 30.0; y: 50.0; srid: 4326
>>> pnt.transform(trans)
>>> print 'x: %s; y: %s; srid: %s' % (pnt.x, pnt.y, pnt.srid)
x: 11160773.5712; y: 19724623.9117; srid: 22186
```